# Property 'push' does not exist on type '() => AppRouterInstance

Tags: next.js

I have got an error Property 'push' does not exist on type '() => AppRouterInstance

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: router.push is not a function is to be fixed


"use client";
import {useRouter}  from "next/navigation";
// import { useRouter } from "next/router";
const Home=()=> {
  const router=(n)=>useRouter();
  const navigate=(name:string)=>{
    router.push(name)
  };
  return (
    <main>
      <h1>Basic routing</h1>
 
      <button type="button" onClick={() =>navigate('/about')}>About Page</button>
    </main>
  );
}
export default Home;
```

this is the problems related to next js , when i use router.push funtion , I have got an error

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
  const router = useRouter();
  const navigate=(name:string)=>{
    router.push(name)
  };
```

Simply assign the return object which is `AppRouterInstance` of `useRouter` to `router`. In your code, if you log `router` it would be a function and not of type `AppRouterInstance`, that's why you are getting this error.